# Which encryption algorithms does AWS Amplify use for iOs apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, aws-amplify, standards-compliance

I am publishing my mobile app to the app store, it asks what type of encryption algorithm does my application uses and the options are:

- Encryption algorithms that are proprietary or not accepted as standard by international standard bodies (IEEE, IETF, ITU, etc.)
- Standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the encryption within Apple's operating system
- Both algorithms mentioned above
- None of the algorithms mentioned above

I have a very simple applications which only uses AWS Amplify for authentication to process user interactions , none of the sensitive user information is stored and I don't use any HTTPS requests or anything besides AWS.

I am expecting it to be the second option which is Standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the encryption within Apple's operating system but I am not sure thus why I am asking this question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have had the same question since they introduced the new Export Compliance dialog back in December, I think (for everyone or for my app specifically?)

Previously it just asked "Are you using any encryption, including standard? - Yes/No" and if yes, then "Is it exempt under export laws? - Yes/No"